# Jenkins/Hudson job parameters at runtime?

Tags: hudson, jenkins, hudson-plugins, jenkins-plugins

**PROBLEM**

Let's say I have a jenkins/hudson job (for example free-style) that takes two parameters **PARAM_ONE** and **PARAM_TWO**. Now, I do not know the values of those parameters, but I can run some script (perl/shell) to find values of those parameters and then I want the user to select from a dropdown list after which I can start the build.

Is there any way of doing that?

Comment: You mean something like choices in parameterized builds ("This build is parameterized" > "Choice"), but where the choices are dynamically determined?

Comment: Yes, that's correct. I just found out that Extended Choice Parameter plugin can read a properties file, and I just checked it does that each time I build a job, and that's exactly what I want. But there is one little hack: How can I access those parameters in a script (for example pre-build step script, perl/shell)?

Comment: I what you really mean is: "How can I set values of those parameters from a script after "schedule a build" button was pressed, but before the parameters page is displayed". Right?

Comment: Yes, in other words I want the parameters to be updated dynamically. But it seems like the plugin I mention read from a properties file, and displays the choices each time I schedule a build. And the accepted answer gives me the parameters in case I want the value of the parameters from pre/post-build scripts.

Comment: Not sure if I understand: how are you running your pre-build script?

Comment: So; I make a properties file, and use the Extended Choice Parameter plugin to set parametrized build, which, each time I schedule the build, reads the file (in case of new property values) and displayes those for me to choose. Then I can access those parameters in my job as described in the accepted answer. I am using groovy to choose the parameters.

Comment: But when do you change the properties file in case it needs to be changed? You can't do it after the build has been scheduled - that's my question.

Comment: Ya, I am sorry, you'r right. I do that externally every night with a cron. BY THE WAY, DO YOU WHAT YOU THOUGHT IS POSSIBLE, anyhow? Would be mind-blowing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sounds like you've found a plug-in that does what you need, that is pretty similar to the built-in *Parameterized Builds* functionality.

To answer your second question: when you define parameterized builds, the parameters are typically passed to your job as environment variables. So you'd access them however you access environment variables in your language, for instance, if you defined a parameter `PARAM_ONE`, you'd access it as:

In bash:

```
$PARAM_ONE
```

In Windows batch:

```
%PARAM_ONE%
```

In Python:

```
import os
os.getenv('PARAM_ONE')
```

etc.

I imagine this would be the same for the Extended Choice Parameter plugin you are using.

Comment: Thanks Jack for a quick answer.

Answer (score 0):

Just install [this](https://github.com/tekante/Dynamic-Jenkins-Parameter/wiki), and give the parameter in the build script like:

Windows

> "your build script" %PARAMONE% %PARAMTWO%

Answer (score 0):

In Java, you can access these parameters off the run object

```
EnvVars envVars = new EnvVars();
envVars = run.getEnvironment(listener);
for (String envName2 : envVars.keySet()) {
   listener.getLogger().println(envName2 + " = " + envVars.get(envName2));
}
```